# Bootstrap 4 - Slick Slider Gradient Effect On Partial Next Slide

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I am currently working on a responsive carousel using boostrap-4 and slick.js. As the center-mode is enabled, it shows partial next slide. I want to put a gradient on the partial next-slide. I have gone through documentation, but unsure how to achieve this.

Here is a link to [Codepen] (https://codepen.io/bzaidi/pen/MWamJvZ)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/div7rpa.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-DHF4zGyjT7GOMPBwpeehwoey18z8uiz98G4PRu2lV0A="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css"
  integrity="sha256-4hqlsNP9KM6+2eA8VUT0kk4RsMRTeS7QGHIM+MZ5sLY="
  crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css"
  integrity="sha256-UK1EiopXIL+KVhfbFa8xrmAWPeBjMVdvYMYkTAEv/HI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"/>

           <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.whatsNextSlick').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,

        responsive: [
               {
                breakpoint:767,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite:true,
                   centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '20%'
                }

            }

//            {
//                    breakpoint:980,
//                    settings: {
//                    slidesToShow: 2,
//                    slidesToScroll: 1,
//                    infinite:true
//                  
//                }
//            
//                
//            }



        ]
    });



  });
</script>

      <style type="text/css">

              .whats-next-container{
          background-color: rgba(188,161,204,0.1);

    }

    .whats-next-container .insideContainer{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        max-width:290px;

    }

    .whats-next-container .leftContent img{
       float:left;
       clear:left;
        margin-right:14px;
    }

     .whats-next-container .rightContent {
      height:159px;
    }

     .whats-next-container .rightContent h4{
        padding-top: 14px;
        padding-right:20px;
    }

    .whats-next-container .rightContent h4 {
        padding-top: 14px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-family: Beausite Fit Regular;
        line-height: 22px;
        font-size: 17.5px !important;
        letter-spacing: -0.48px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #41173F;
    }


    .whats-next-container .rightContent a.whatsNextLink{
        display:flex !important;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        margin-top:30px;
        border:0px;
    }




.whatsNextSlick .slick-prev,
.whatsNextSlick  .slick-next{
    background:transparent;
    border-radius:0;

}



.whatsNextSlick  .slick-prev {
    left: -25px;
}

.whatsNextSlick .slick-next {
    right: -25px;
}

.whatsNextSlick .slick-prev,
.whatsNextSlick .slick-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
    content: '‹';
}

.slick-next:before {
    content: '›';

}

.slick-next:before,
.slick-prev:before {
    font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif !important;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 30px;    
}





    @media(max-width: 767px) {
        .slick-list {
            padding-left: 0px!important; 
        }

    .whatsNextSlick .slick-prev, .whatsNextSlick .slick-next {
        background: transparent !important;
        top: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        border-radius: 0;


     }
        .whatsNextSlick .slick-prev{
             right: 30px;
        left: unset;
        }

    }


/*         @media(max-width: 360px) and (min-width:320px)*/
    @media only screen and (max-width:320px)
         {

        .whatsNextSlick .leftContent img{
/*            width:40%*/
            height:159px;

        }

        .whats-next-container .rightContent h4 {
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            font-family: Beausite Fit Regular;
            line-height: 17px;
            font-size: 14px !important;
            letter-spacing: -0.48px;
            text-align: left;
            color: #41173F;
        }

        .whats-next-container .rightContent a.whatsNextLink {
            display: flex !important;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            border: 0px;
        }

    }



        @media(max-width: 375px) and (min-width:360px) {

        .whatsNextSlick .leftContent img{
/*            width:40%*/
            height:159px;

        }

        .whats-next-container .rightContent h4 {
               padding-top: 10px;
                padding-right: 11px;
                font-family: Beausite Fit Regular;
                line-height: 17px;
                font-size: 17.5px !important;
                letter-spacing: -0.48px;
                text-align: left;
                color: #41173F;
        }


       .whats-next-container .rightContent a.whatsNextLink {
            display: flex !important;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            border: 0px;
            }

    }



     @media(max-width:980px) and (min-width:900px) {
            .whats-next-container .rightContent h4 {
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            font-family: Beausite Fit Regular;
            line-height: 18px;
            font-size: 15.5px !important;
            letter-spacing: -0.48px;
            text-align: left;
            color: #41173F;
        }

        .whats-next-container .rightContent a.whatsNextLink {
            display: flex !important;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-top: 16px;
            border: 0px;
        }
        .whats-next-container .leftContent img {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    }


      </style>
  </head>
  <body>




         <!-- What's Next Carousel -->

    <div class="container-fluid whats-next-container">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-block d-sm-flex">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <h3>What's Next</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 mb-4 mt-4">
                    <div class="whatsNextSlick">

                        <div class="slide1Container">
                            <div class="insideContainer">
                                <div class="leftContainer">
                                    <div class="leftContent">
                                          <picture>
                                            <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg" class="justBecause"/>
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg"  class="justBecause" />
                                        </picture>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="rightContainer">
                                    <div class="rightContent">

<!--                                        <p class="heading">Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</p>-->
                                          <h4>Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</h4>
                                         <a href="#" class="btn-primary cta body-font whatsNextLink" >Browse Catalogue ›</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                          <div class="slide1Container">
                            <div class="insideContainer">
                                <div class="leftContainer">
                                    <div class="leftContent">
                                       <picture>
                                            <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg" class="justBecause"/>
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg"  class="justBecause" />
                                        </picture>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="rightContainer">
                                    <div class="rightContent">

                                        <h4>Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</h4>
                                         <a href="#" class="btn-primary cta body-font whatsNextLink">Browse Catalogue ›</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                          <div class="slide1Container">
                            <div class="insideContainer">
                                <div class="leftContainer">
                                    <div class="leftContent">
                                          <picture>
                                            <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg" class="justBecause"/>
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg"  class="justBecause" />
                                        </picture>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="rightContainer">
                                    <div class="rightContent">

                                        <h4>Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</h4>
                                         <a href="#" class="btn-primary cta body-font whatsNextLink">Browse Catalogue ›</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                          <div class="slide1Container">
                            <div class="insideContainer">
                                <div class="leftContainer">
                                    <div class="leftContent">
                                        <picture>
                                            <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg" class="justBecause"/>
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg"  class="justBecause" />
                                        </picture>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="rightContainer">
                                    <div class="rightContent">

                                        <h4>Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</h4>
                                         <a href="#" class="btn-primary cta body-font whatsNextLink">Browse Catalogue ›</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                          <div class="slide1Container">
                            <div class="insideContainer">
                                <div class="leftContainer">
                                    <div class="leftContent">
                                          <picture>
                                            <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg" class="justBecause"/>
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MV0f4wd/whatsnew-image-01.jpg"  class="justBecause" />
                                        </picture>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="rightContainer">
                                    <div class="rightContent">

                                        <h4>Our Mother's Day Gift Guide is out now!</h4>
                                         <a href="#" class="btn-primary cta body-font whatsNextLink">Browse Catalogue ›</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>     


    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone guide me, please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

### First of all, while comparing your CSS classes to slick.js documentation, i figured that out :

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMU3C.png), you see that **Slick.js** Center Mode carousel is setting the center slide as **current** slide

Now, [in your CodePen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWxF2.png) (which i tested on a local file), your offset was shifted on the left (the current was the first slide showed on the left of the carousel... not so centered for a centered mode).

### **What did it for me :**

**1. I first pasted the JS code [from Slick.js Center Mode](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) *as is*.**

> Why ? In order to get the behaviour right and to get a clean code.
>
> Your JS was customized and, for example, had  `centerMode: true`
>   **deleted from the main part** of the code.

**2. Draw a visual representation of what you want in order to target what to edit (CSS, JS ?)**

> [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWxF2.png) i've drawn which kind of visual representation you should have in your head 
>   before getting to work on a graphical customization
>
> The best way to create a gradient when skick.js loads its classes
>   after the document loads is to put the gradient UNDER the forthcoming
>   content.
>
> Hence, i added these jQuery **insertBefore** and **insertBefore** to wrap the slider

```
    $( "<div style='height:100%;width:100%;background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #2e2e2e, #585858, #878787, #b9b9b9, #b9b9b9, #b9b9b9, #b9b9b9, #878787, #585858, #2e2e2e, #000000);position:absolute;'>" ).insertBefore( "div.slick-slider" );
    $( "</div>" ).insertAfter( "div.slick-slider" );
```

> Edit 1 : Which is the Overlay div, basically.
>   I could have added the wrap jQuery function tho

**3. After that, custom the `slick-slide` and `slick-center` class**

```
        .slick-slide {
    opacity: .4;
    }
        .slick-center {
    display: block;
    max-width: 10% !important;
    max-height:20% !important;
    opacity: 1;
```

> The opacity is set in order to let the gradient below appear
>
> Found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30951516/13407155

**4. Finally, here's a working solution [on a CodePen](https://codepen.io/hotlinedelite/pen/GRpmbgZ)**

Comment: Thank you so much mate. I will be looking into it and i will update you with my results. Thank you so much for immense clarity.

Comment: Hey, if this has been helpful, could you mark it as an answer ?